# Joining Enterprise Attribute Data View and Business Unit List Subscribers Data View

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, custom-profile, data-views

I need to query subscriber profile attributes, which are only available at the parent Enterprise level **EnterpriseAttribute** Data View, together with the subscriber’s Status in the child Business Unit level **ListSubscribers** Data View.

Because I am querying **EnterpriseAttribute** Data View, I have to write the SQL at the Enterprise level. However, I don’t know how to target a Business Unit level **ListSubscribers** Data View from there. It seems that when you are at the Enterprise level, **ListSubscribers** only refers to the **All Subscribers List**. I tried using **ListID** of the BU List as a condition, but it does not return any result. A subscriber may be unsubscribed at the BU level but still remains active at the Enterprise level. Therefore, I need to know the Status specific to the former.

Here is what I have thus far:

---

```
SELECT lst.subscriberkey AS 'Subscriber Key', 
       lst.emailaddress  AS 'Email Address', 
       firstname         AS 'FirstName', 
       lastname          AS 'LastName', 
       address1          AS 'Address1', 
       city              AS 'City', 
       state             AS 'State', 
       postalcode        AS 'PostalCode', 
       banner            AS 'Banner', 
       bannerweekly      AS 'BannerWeekly', 
       bannerspecials    AS 'BannerSpecials', 
       bannermonthly     AS 'BannerMonthly', 
       lst.status        AS 'Status', 
       lst.listid        AS 'ListID' 
FROM   _enterpriseattribute ent 
       INNER JOIN _listsubscribers lst 
               ON ent._subscriberid = lst.subscriberid 
       INNER JOIN _sent snt 
               ON lst.subscriberid = snt.subscriberid 
WHERE 
  oybaccountid = 1234567 /* Child Business Unit OYBAccountID (MID) */
  AND lst.listid = 1234 /* Child Business Unit ListID */
  AND bannerweekly = 'N' 
  AND bannerspecials = 'N' 
  AND bannermonthly = 'N' 
  AND lst.status = 'Active'
```

---

Update: 2018-07-12 2:00 PM (Central)

I have “Subscribers will be unsubscribed from all business units in the Enterprise” selected. Here are updates to my SQL / Automation: At the Enterprise level, I query the 3 banner profile attributes and the All Subscribers List. The Target Data Extension is at the Shared item level.

---

```
SELECT lst.subscriberkey AS 'SubscriberKey', 
       lst.emailaddress  AS 'EmailAddress', 
       firstname         AS 'FirstName', 
       lastname          AS 'LastName', 
       address1          AS 'Address1', 
       city              AS 'City', 
       state             AS 'State', 
       postalcode        AS 'PostalCode', 
       banner            AS 'Banner', 
       bannerweekly      AS 'BannerWeekly', 
       bannerspecials    AS 'BannerSpecials', 
       bannermonthly     AS 'BannerMonthly', 
       lst.status        AS 'Status', 
       lst.listname      AS 'ListName'  
FROM   _enterpriseattribute ent 
       INNER JOIN _listsubscribers lst 
               ON ent._subscriberid = lst.subscriberid 
WHERE 
  lst.listname = 'All Subscribers'
  AND bannerweekly = 'N' 
  AND bannerspecials = 'N' 
  AND bannermonthly = 'N' 
  AND lst.status = 'Active'
```

---

I then switch to the BU level and query the Data Extension above with the BU Subscriber List:

---

```
SELECT lst.subscriberkey AS 'SubscriberKey', 
       lst.emailaddress  AS 'EmailAddress', 
       firstname         AS 'FirstName', 
       lastname          AS 'LastName', 
       address1          AS 'Address1', 
       city              AS 'City', 
       state             AS 'State', 
       postalcode        AS 'PostalCode', 
       banner            AS 'Banner', 
       bannerweekly      AS 'BannerWeekly', 
       bannerspecials    AS 'BannerSpecials', 
       bannermonthly     AS 'BannerMonthly', 
       lst.status        AS 'Status', 
       lst.listname      AS 'ListName' 
FROM   ent.email_preferences_status_de ent 
       INNER JOIN _listsubscribers lst 
               ON ent.subscriberkey = lst.subscriberkey 
WHERE
  lst.listname = 'BU Subscriber List'
  AND lst.status = 'Active'
```

---

It seems to be working.

Comment: BU level unsubscribes cannot be accessed via Data Views - it needs to set up a Mock list in each BU where those subscribers will be re-imported to mock list and hence it will show you the correct status. I am happy to post the solution to retain the correct status if you wish

Comment: Brad, Thanks. Yes, please post a solution. I appreciate it. I was thinking: For the above SQL, the Target Data Extension is at the Shared Items folder, which I can access at the child BU level. I can write another SQL at the child BU level, to join the Target Data Extension with the ENT. prefix and the ListSubscribers Data View of the child BU. Since now I am at the child BU level, the ListSubscribers Data View is the one I want to query the status of. The down side is that I have to repeat the same process within each individual BU, 4 total. I wish there’s a better way. Thanks again.

Comment: Can you please check under Admin>Business Units>Unsubscribe Settings? If the unsubscribes are handled in BU level then the solution I post will need an automation setup if you require the BU level status frequently.

Comment: Brad, please see edit in Update: 2018-07-12 2:00 PM.